# Proofs as games?

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, education

A long time ago (but I can't remember when), I was introduced to the (pedagogical) concept of writing a proof as giving a winning strategy for a game.  Basically, given a statement $\forall x\exists y \forall z\exists w P(x,y,z,w)$ (or similar), there is a corresponding game, where one player is $\forall$ (sometimes pronounced $\forall$belard or $\forall$dversary), the other player is $\exists$ (sometimes pronounced $\exists$loise, which is apparently hilarious if you know French).

Anyway, the objective of $\forall$ is to make $P$ false; the objective of $\exists$ is to make $P$ true.  They take turns playing (turn order defined by quantifier order) and the statement is true if and only if $\exists$ has a winning strategy.

Of course you'd have to prove this makes sense, but the above can be made a theorem and proven.  However, I'm teaching a course on proof, and can't for the life of me find a citation for any of this for my students to read.  Not the applications of this into model theory, etc., but just the explanation of this as a metaphor.

Is this familiar to anyone?  And can you remember where you saw it before?  I'm trying to find something tangible I can give to my students.

Comment: While I am looking for a reference for you, you may enjoy reading about [Peter $\forall$belard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Abelard) and [$\acute\exists$loïse d'Argenteuil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9lo%C3%AFse_d%27Argenteuil)

Comment: I’m afraid that I’ve known (and used) it for so long that I’ve no idea where I first encountered it.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia has an article about this](http://enwp.org/Game_semantics) although it isn't very good, but it does have many other references you could consult.

The idea is crucial to understanding why [the strategies of so many games are PSPACE-complete](http://enwp.org/Game_complexity#Complexities_of_some_well-known_games). This is because the central PSPACE-complete problem, analogous to SAT for NP-complete problems, is [the satisfiability problem for quantified boolean formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBF), and asserting that $P_1$ wins some game can be understood as claiming that there exists a $P_1$ move such that for all $P_2$ moves there exists a $P_1$ move… etc.

Comment: Hmm, one of the mathematicians specifically mentioned in the Wikipedia article is [Andreas Blass](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/48510/andreas-blass), who is a regular here.  I wonder if saying @andreas-blass will invoke him?

Comment: The part of the article that's at the appropriate level (very low) is pretty small, and it gets too advanced quickly.  The students I want to give this too are not very high-level at all.

Answer (score 1):

Pavel Pudlak's [*Proofs as Games*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589349?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) would be a place to look.